# Replacing ObjectId with embedded json when marshaling struct

Tags: json, mongodb, go

I'm building a RESTful API with Go and MongoDB, and I'm running into some difficulty with embedding the JSON for one document inside the JSON for another. Here's a toy example of what I'm trying to accomplish. I have the following schemas:

```
type Post struct {
    ID    bson.ObjectId `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Title string        `json:"title,omitempty"`
    Owner bson.ObjectId `json:"owner,omitempty"` // references a User
}

type User struct {
    ID   bson.ObjectId `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Name string        `json:"name,omitempty"`
}
```

When creating the JSON for a post, I'd like to first look up the owner of the post in MongoDB and embed the resulting user inside said post's JSON (in-place of the original `ObjectId`), like so:

```
{
    "id": "...",
    "title": "My awesome post",
    "owner": {
        "id": "...",
        "name": "Cody"
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this, other than manually constructing the JSON using `map[string]interface{}`, like so:

```
post := LookupPost(...)
user := LookupUser(post.Owner)

m := map[string]interface{}{
    "id": post.ID,
    "title": post.Title,
    "owner": map[string]interface{}{
        "id": user.ID,
        "name": user.Name,
    },
}

b, _ := json.Marshal(m)
```

Obviously this <strike>doesn't scale very well</strike> isn't very DRY -- ideally, I'd be able to utilize the `json` tags in each struct definition and have the fields inserted automatically.

Am I missing something, or is what I'm trying to do impossible? Or am I simply not approaching MongoDB/JSON in Go correctly? To put things in perspective, I'm coming from a Node.js background, where this sort of functionality is trivial.

**Edit**

To clarify things, here's some incorrect Go code that shows what I'd like to do

```
func getPostJSON() []byte {
    p := LookupPost(...)
    u := LookupUser(p.Owner, ...)

    uj, _ := json.Marshal(u)
    p.Owner = uj // can't do this in Go

    pj, _ := json.Marshal(p)

    return pj
}
```

Comment: _"Obviously this doesn't scale very well"_ Do you just want to get rid of the recursive call ? Or are you looking for some kind of proxy object accessing the underlying DB to retrieve data on a per-need basis ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Sorry for the ambiguity! I meant that it doesn't scale well in terms of the complexity of the code. I'm mostly concerned with keeping things DRY -- there's some implications in regards to my project's structure (which would take to long to describe) as to why I want to avoid manually piecing together the json.

Comment: I put `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"id,omitempty"` in fromt of an string field, and worked like a charm.

Comment: Adding a simple `bson:"_id"` to a string field does the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I actually discovered a much cleaner solution to this problem:

```
type Post struct {
    ID bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"id,omitempty"`
    Title string `bson:"title,omitempty" json:"title,omitempty"`
    Owner UserRef `bson:"owner,omitempty" json:"owner,omitempty"`
}

type User struct {
    ID   bson.ObjectId `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Name string        `json:"name,omitempty"`
}

type UserRef bson.ObjectId

func (ref UserRef) GetBSON() (interface{}, error) {
    return bson.ObjectId(ref), nil
}

func (ref UserRef) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    u := LookupUserInMongoDB(ref)

    return json.Marshal(u)
}
```

Here's how it works -- mgo can't store UserRef as an ObjectId when converting a Post to bson, so we can implement the `GetBSON` method for UserRef to return the underlying ObjectId. This allows us to store Owner as an ObjectId in the database. And, like in @DaveC's answer, we implement the `MarshalJSON` method for UserRef so that when converting a Post to json, we can replace the ObjectId with an actual embedded user.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familar with MongoDB or `bson.ObjectId`, but can you substitute your own type for your `User` field and have MongoDB easily fill that in for you from a user's `bson.ObjectId`?

If so you can just wrap user object id's into their own type that implements the `json.Marshaler` interface. E.g.:

```
// Embedded (instead of `type x bson.ObjectId`) so that we
// get all the methods and satisfy all the interfaces that
// bson.ObjectId does. Hopefully that's engough to allow MongoDB
// to fill in fields of this type from a database??
type ownerObjID struct{ bson.ObjectId }

// Here we marshal the results of looking up the user from the id
// rather than just the ID itself.
func (oid ownerObjID) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    user, err := LookupUser(oid.ObjectId)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return json.Marshal(user)
}

type Post struct {
    ID    bson.ObjectId `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Title string        `json:"title,omitempty"`
    Owner ownerObjID    `json:"owner,omitempty"` // <-- is this type wrapping doable/easy with MongoDB?
}

type User struct {
    ID   bson.ObjectId `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Name string        `json:"name,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    post := LookupPost()
    b, err := json.MarshalIndent(post, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("JSON:\n%s\n", b)
}

// Some stubs for demo:
func LookupPost() Post {
    return Post{
        ID:    "postID001",
        Title: "Ima Test",
        Owner: ownerObjID{"ownerID002"},
    }
}

func LookupUser(id bson.ObjectId) (User, error) {
    return User{
        ID:   id,
        Name: "name for " + string(id),
    }, nil
}
```

[<kbd>Playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/ds-u3lfEzu)

Gives me:

```
JSON:
{
  "id": "postID001",
  "title": "Ima Test",
  "owner": {
    "id": "ownerID002",
    "name": "name for ownerID002"
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for! Although for future reference, I had to make some adjustments to make it compatible with MongoDB -- you need to add a `bson:",inline"` tag next `Owner ownerObjID`, and a `bson:"owner"` tag next to `bson.ObjectId` in `struct ownerObjID`. This will store the ObjectId in MongoDB correctly under the name "owner".